# How to debug NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER when mounting cifs share?

Tags: mount, windows, cifs

Mounting cifs share exported by one host (hostx) works ok:

```
[piotr@demon ~]$ sudo mount -t cifs //hostx.intranet.local/pdobrogost /home/piotr/remote/hostx/ --verbose -o credentials=/home/piotr/.config/cifs-credentials.conf,uid=piotr,gid=piotr
domain=domainx
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=1.2.3.4,unc=\\hostx.intranet.local\pdobrogost,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=pdobrogost,,domain=domainx,pass=********
```

The same does not work for cifs share exported by another host (hosty):

```
[piotr@demon ~]$ sudo mount -t cifs //hosty.intranet.local/pdobrogost /home/piotr/remote/hosty/ --verbose -o credentials=/home/piotr/.config/cifs-credentials.conf,uid=piotr,gid=piotr
domain=domainx
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=1.2.3.5,unc=\\hosty.intranet.local\pdobrogost,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=pdobrogost,,domain=domainx,pass=********
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

`/home/piotr/.config/cifs-credentials.conf` looks like this:

```
username=my_cifs_username
password=my_cifs_password
domain=domainx
```

I tried connecting to cifs share on hosty using `smbclient` and got this:

```
[piotr@demon ~]$ smbclient -d 3 -A /home/piotr/.config/cifs-credentials.conf -W domainx //hosty.intranet.local/pdobrogost
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
params.c:pm_process() - Processing configuration file "/etc/samba/smb.conf"
Processing section "[global]"
added interface p1p1 ip=10.92.2.80 bcast=10.92.2.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
Client started (version 4.1.6).
tdb(/var/lib/samba/gencache.tdb): tdb_open_ex: could not open file /var/lib/samba/gencache.tdb: Permission denied
resolve_lmhosts: Attempting lmhosts lookup for name hosty.intranet.local<0x20>
resolve_lmhosts: Attempting lmhosts lookup for name hosty.intranet.local<0x20>
resolve_wins: WINS server resolution selected and no WINS servers listed.
resolve_hosts: Attempting host lookup for name hosty.intranet.local<0x20>
Connecting to 1.2.3.5 at port 445
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=97)
got OID=1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
got OID=1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=cifs/hosty.intranet.local@INTRANET.LOCAL
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60898215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
SPNEGO login failed: Unexpected information received
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
```

local system running Fedora 20
mount.cifs version: 6.3
smbclient version: 4.1.6
hostx running Debian 6.0.10
Samba version on hostx: 2:3.5.6~dfsg-3squeeze11
hosty running Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 4
Samba version on hosty: samba-3.0.33-0.19.el4_8.3

In samba logs on hosty there are the following entries:

```
Nov 14 15:09:37 hosty smbd[28956]: [2014/11/14 15:09:37, 0] rpc_client/cli_pipe.c:cli_pipe_verify_schannel(354)
Nov 14 15:09:37 hosty smbd[28956]:   cli_pipe_verify_schannel: auth_len 56.
Nov 14 15:09:37 hosty smbd[28956]: [2014/11/14 15:09:37, 0] auth/auth_domain.c:domain_client_validate(260)
Nov 14 15:09:37 hosty smbd[28956]:   domain_client_validate: unable to validate password for user pdobrogost in domain domainx to Domain controller A.INTRANET.LOCAL. Error was NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER.
```

which would suggest the problem lies in authorizing my password by Active Directory domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

Can you also run smbclient with the hostx, and share the results ?
If it works you should maybe compare the smb conf file for both hosts (from your results, it seems that it is file: /etc/samba/smb.conf).
Have you checked that SPNEGO is configured on your server ? If it's not the case, you should maybe disable it by adding this in the smb.conf settings of hosty:

[global]

client use spnego = No